# NetTCP and binary transfer

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF Service with HTTP bindings which returns dataset on 500k size.
When using WCF default logging I can see the messages and data being transfered with each message

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!-- add trace logging -->
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
      <messageLogging
           logEntireMessage="true"
           logMalformedMessages="true"
           logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
           logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
           maxMessagesToLog="3000"
       />
    </diagnostics>

    ....

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add initializeData="c:\nettcpTestLOCALToTEST.xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
            name="messages">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Point is, I am looking for a way to reduce the traffic between server and client, and I have been told that NetTCP is transferring the data binary? Is that correct?

I have set up a test scenario with a NetTCPBinding and when I read the WCF on the client side, the Response Message includes the whole dataset schema and data in XML format. Is it just serialized so the can be written to a log, or was this message transfered binary?

Is the amount of data being transfered with a NetTCP binding smaller than with HTTPBinding? Is it text or binary?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes the message will be transfered binary but the Serializer (Datacontractserializer I assume) will serialize the data in XML format:

> Use the DataContractSerializer class to serialize and deserialize instances of a type into an XML stream or document

[DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx)
From the docu:

> The NetTcpBinding generates a run-time communication stack by default, which uses transport security, TCP for message delivery, and a binary message encoding. This binding is an appropriate system-provided choice for communicating over an Intranet.

[NetTcpBinding MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx)

If you opt to implement ISerializable you can use WCF too but you have to implement an DataContractResolver to resolve the types: if the client "knows" the Types (for example you put them into a dll and add them to the client-app) you can use the following example-code (sorry I only have this in F# around but you should find it easy to translate)
This should yield the serialization in more compact form.

```
type internal SharedTypeResolver() =
    inherit System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractResolver()

    let dict = new Xml.XmlDictionary()

    override this.TryResolveType(t : Type, declaredT : Type, knownTypeResolver : System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractResolver, typeName : Xml.XmlDictionaryString byref, typeNamespace : Xml.XmlDictionaryString byref) =
        typeNamespace = dict.Add(t.Assembly.FullName)
        typeName = dict.Add(t.FullName)
        true

    override this.ResolveName(typeName : string, typeNamespace : string, declaredType : Type, knownTypeResolver : System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractResolver) =
        let res = knownTypeResolver.ResolveName(typeName, typeNamespace, declaredType, null)
        if res = null then Type.GetType(typeName + ", " + typeNamespace) else res
```

PS: found the same in C#:

```
    public class SharedTypeResolver : DataContractResolver
    {
        #region Overrides of DataContractResolver

        /// 
        /// Override this method to map a data contract type to an xsi:type name and namespace during serialization.
        /// 
        /// 
        /// true if mapping succeeded; otherwise, false.
        /// 
        /// The type to map.The type declared in the data contract.The known type resolver.The xsi:type name.The xsi:type namespace.
        public override bool TryResolveType(Type type, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver, out XmlDictionaryString typeName, out XmlDictionaryString typeNamespace)
        {
            if (!knownTypeResolver.TryResolveType(type, declaredType, null, out typeName, out typeNamespace))
            {
                var dict = new XmlDictionary(); // nice trick to get the right type for typeName
                if (type != null)
                {
                    typeNamespace = dict.Add(type.Assembly.FullName);
                    typeName = dict.Add(type.FullName);
                }
                else
                {
                    typeNamespace = dict.Add("noAss");
                    typeName = dict.Add("noType");
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        /// 
        /// Override this method to map the specified xsi:type name and namespace to a data contract type during deserialization.
        /// 
        /// 
        /// The type the xsi:type name and namespace is mapped to. 
        /// 
        /// The xsi:type name to map.The xsi:type namespace to map.The type declared in the data contract.The known type resolver.
        public override Type ResolveName(string typeName, string typeNamespace, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver)
        {
            return knownTypeResolver.ResolveName(typeName, typeNamespace, declaredType, null) ??
                   Type.GetType(typeName + ", " + typeNamespace);
        }
```

(Please note: stackoverflow don't like the assignmentoperator "<-" from F# and i don't know how to circumvent - therefore I used "=")
oh well - I guess I have to say how to add those resolvers to your host:

```
        private static void AddResolver(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {
            if (operationDescription == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();

            var serializationBehavior = operationDescription.Behaviors.Find();
            if (serializationBehavior == null)
            {
                serializationBehavior = new DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(operationDescription);
                operationDescription.Behaviors.Add(serializationBehavior);
            }
            serializationBehavior.DataContractResolver = new SharedTypeResolver();
        }
```

use this with:

```
            var contrDescription = _host.Description.Endpoints[0].Contract;
            var description= contrDescription.Operations.Find("MyServiceMethod");
            AddResolver(description);
```

replacing "MyServiceMethod" by the name of your service-method (on call per method or you iterate over all of them)

Comment: thanks! but if I don't implement your resolver class, will the data being transfered over the network still be less than with an HttpBinding?

Comment: without the resolver your client won't know what to do with the data comming (but try: it's a while since I wrote this - maybe they look for known types in your assembly - but I doubt it because in the beginning you had to name additional "KnownTypes" inside your contract-definition)

Comment: here is a nice article on that matter: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/06/05/introducing-a-new-datacontractserializer-feature-the-datacontractresolver.aspx (well I guess I just could have linked this ... my code is straight from this article ;) )

Comment: I have done some tests and it shows that I get a 30% traffic reduction with switching from WSHTTP to NetTCP. I actually hoped for more reduction since it now is binary transfer :/

Comment: I forgot to say that this is a .net 3.5 application. Your article is about 4.0?

Comment: @Martin: yes the DataContractResolver was shipped in .net 4.0 - sorry didn't know. I think you can do similar things in .net 3.5 but you have to dig yourself deep into WCF and I can't help you much since I never did

Comment: maybe I have another solution: change your contract to return byte[] and use BinaryFormatter in the solution I gave to transfer a Object into a byte[] - Array and vice versa. This is a hack at best (and not far from using a TCP-Socket instead of WCF - which might be better) - but should do it